# c++ program for rotation of matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

Please forgive me if my question is not good ,I am new here

**Task :**
Rotate the given matrix by 180 degree

Input:

> ```
> 1
> 4
> 1 2 3 4
> 5 6 7 8
> 9 10 11 12
> 13 14 15 16
> ```

Output:

> ```
> 16 15 14 13
> 12 11 10 9
> 8  7  6 5
> 4 3 2 1
> ```

**What I have Tried**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int a[15][15];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                cin >> a[i][j];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int p = n - 1;
            for (int j = 0; j <= (n - 1) / 2; j++)
                swap(a[i][j], a[i][p--]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int p = n - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1) / 2; i++)
                swap(a[i][j], a[p--][j]);
        }
        cout << "checking if printing all row or not" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Failed at test case**

Input:

```
10

    220 892 951 241 739 884 66 815 904 660

    85 784 379 346 598 873 716 535 422 902

    579 872 41 870 827 406 910 583 349 896

    771 817 361 591 212 74 199 421 820 176

    496 771 558 954 889 628 126 250 58 156

    683 88 339 58 436 176 57 459 22 394

    43 280 839 618 688 573 493 178 941 504

    420 676 888 935 95 593 616 833 115 210

    339 798 694 515 7 831 103 947 992 724

    195 904 864 51 174 980 960 4 974 509
```

Its Correct output is :

```
    509 974 4 960 980 174 51 864 904 195

    724 992 947 103 831 7 515 694 798 339

    210 115 833 616 593 95 935 888 676 420

    504 941 178 493 573 688 618 839 280 43

    394 22 459 57 176 436 58 339 88 683

    156 58 250 126 628 889 954 558 771 496

    176 820 421 199 74 212 591 361 817 771

    896 349 583 910 406 827 870 41 872 579

    902 422 535 716 873 598 346 379 784 85

    660 904 815 66 884 739 241 951 892 220
```

And online judge says that

And Your Code's output is:

```
509 974 4 960 980 174 51 864 904 195

724 992 947 103 831 7 515 694 798 339

210 115 833 616 593 95 935 888 676 420

504 941 178 493 573 688 618 839 280 43

156 58 250 126 628 889 954 558 771 496
```

But when I debug my program I saw that whole roatated matrix was correct.
am i doing mistake in c++ ? I am new to c++ Please help.

for input output constraint:
 [Question Link](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/c-matrix-rotation-by-180-degree/0)

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: note that if your task is to print the rotated matrix, then you dont actually have to rotate the matrix. You can use the same index-transformation you use now to directly print it rotated

Comment: Just to be sure, when you sending code to online judge, did you removed: `cout << "checking if printing all row or not" << endl;`? You should! Your code should print only what is described in the task.

Comment: is it possible that the last `" "` should not be part of the output? I once wasted some time on a "problem" like that, just to arrive at the conclusion that online judges dont teach you anything but how to make online judges happy

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/BO149HGxRE0bwOCi

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int p = n - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < (n - 1) / 2; i++)
                swap(a[i][j], a[p--][j]);
        }
```

### In above inner for-loop you missed "<=". So it should be

```
for (int i = 0; i <= (n - 1) / 2; i++)
```

Your entire code will be

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int a[15][15];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                cin >> a[i][j];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int p = n - 1;
            for (int j = 0; j <= (n - 1) / 2; j++)
                swap(a[i][j], a[i][p--]);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int p = n - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= (n - 1) / 2; i++)
                swap(a[i][j], a[p--][j]);
        }
        cout << "checking if printing all row or not" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                cout << a[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```